# How to create a raw body for POST request using PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying a POST request using PowerShell. It takes body of type raw. I know how to pass form-data using PowerShell, however not sure for rawdata type. For a simple raw-data in Postman e.g.

```
{
"@type":"login",
 "username":"xxx@gmail.com",
 "password":"yyy"
}
```

I pass below in PowerShell and it works fine.

```
$rawcreds = @{
               '@type' = 'login'
                username=$Username
                password=$Password
             }

        $json = $rawcreds | ConvertTo-Json
```

However, for a complex rawdata like below, I am unsure how to pass in PowerShell.

```
{
    "@type": Sample_name_01",
    "agentId": "00000Y08000000000004",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "@type": "TaskParameter",
            "name": "$source$",
            "type": "EXTENDED_SOURCE"
        },
        {
            "@type": "TaskParameter",
            "name": "$target$",
            "type": "TARGET",
            "targetConnectionId": "00000Y0B000000000020",
            "targetObject": "sample_object"
        }
    ],
    "mappingId": "00000Y1700000000000A"
}
```

Comment: The `-Body` parameter of `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` accepts a string, and uses that as a "raw body" so I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: So do you mean, I can pass the whole raw body as it is given below?

Comment: Put the literal (raw) content you want into a string, then pass it in. In your first example, you create an object and then convert it to JSON (a string). Is your "complex" example meant to be raw JSON? And you're unsure how to build that?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My interpretation is that your second code block is the raw JSON you want, and you're not sure how to construct that. The easiest way would be to use a [here string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx):

```
$body = @"
{
    "@type": Sample_name_01",
    "agentId": "00000Y08000000000004",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "@type": "TaskParameter",
            "name": "$source$",
            "type": "EXTENDED_SOURCE"
        },
        {
            "@type": "TaskParameter",
            "name": "$target$",
            "type": "TARGET",
            "targetConnectionId": "00000Y0B000000000020",
            "targetObject": "sample_object"
        }
    ],
    "mappingId": "00000Y1700000000000A"
}
"@

Invoke-WebRequest -Body $body
```

Variable substitution works (because we used `@"` instead of `@'`) but you don't have to do messy escaping of literal `"` characters.

So what that means is that `$source$` will be interpreted as a variable named `$source` to be embedded in the string followed by a literal `$`. If that's not what you want (that is, if you want to literally use `$source$` in the body), then use `@'` and `'@` to enclose your here string so that powershell variables are not embedded.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Its quite helpful. Yes, I wanted to literally use the $source$. I would use @'$source$'@ as you mentioned.